# Unable to download a file completely

Tags: download, iso-image, file-corruption, hashing

Hello I've been trying to download kali-linux-2.0-amd64.iso 3 times.
When I tried it 1st time the file had about 2.6 GB, the hashes didn't coincide. 2nd time the file had 2.5 GB, the hashes didn't coincide. 3rd time the file had 2.8 GB, the hashes didn't coincide again. The file should have 3.1 GB. 1st time I tried downloading via linux kali iceweasel directly, 2nd and 3rd time windows 8.1 chrome directly and now I'm trying via torrent directly. I'd like to know if it's normal to have so huge file size and hash differences, what might cause it and if I might work with it safely.

Thank you for fast responses and sorry for my english.

Answer (score 1):

A 3 GB file is not particularly large. You should not be having a problem.

The hashes don't match because you haven't downloaded the complete file. A hash should only match if you have each and every bit of the file downloaded correctly. If you are missing even one single byte, the hash will not match.

As to why your downloads aren't completing, it is hard to even speculate. Do you have enough space on both your destination drive and on your temporary drive/partition? For Windows 8, this means you'd want to ensure you have at least 7 GB free on your C drive, if only using one drive. Have you scanned your computer's RAM using memtest86? Are you able to download this file on a different computer?